# How can I create a user record with specific language and country?

Tags: apex, user, locale

I need create user via apex with specific lang and country. For example with lang French and country Switzerland. I am trying create user with fields:

```
LanguageLocaleKey='fr_CH',
LocaleSidKey='fr_CH',
```

But using the above values causes this error::

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Language: bad value for restricted picklist field: fr_CH: [LanguageLocaleKey]

Comment: I believe you are passing wrong value in LanguageLocaleKey and LocaleSidKey Pickist. check the value again and try

Comment: Yes. I have figured out with it. I am using LanguageLocaleKey = 'fr' and LocaleSidKey='fr_CH' and all works fine. Anyway thank you for helping!

Answer (score 3):

Congrats on self-curing. For the next person who runs into this issue, the valid values for a restricted picklist can be found by using any of the Metadata browsers that use the Describe API call. A good example is Workbench. This is what it looks like for SObject `User`

[image]

Be sure to use the picklist's `value` attribute "value", not the `label`.